# How to apply SaveAs on Word for Mac?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I have this VBA code in a Word for Mac 2016

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:= _
     "forMerrin.htm", FileFormat:= _
     wdFormatFilteredHTML, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
     :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
     :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
     SaveAsAOCELetter:=False
```

It returns:

> Run-time error: "5460"
> A file error has occurred.
> (forMErrin.htm)

I tried SaveAs2 but still the same problem.

Comment: The filename needs to include the path - "forMerrin.htm" only tells Word what you want to name the file but not where you want to put it.

Comment: Wow, thanks @TimothyRylatt, due to the easiness of the answer, I feel my question is not the smartest one. Thanks again, could you please answer the question so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename needs to include the path - "forMerrin.htm" only tells Word what you want to name the file but not where you want to put it.